# Is it possible to declare js event and/or function using only css3?

Tags: javascript, css

I know there are methods of adding content to a web page like stated here: http://nooshu.com/adding-content-using-css3

But.. I wonder if there is also a possibility to declare a js event in css on given selected nodes, like:

```
.myclass {
   declare-js-event: "onclick";
   declare-js-function: "alert('I've been clicked!')"
}
```

If (as I highly suppose) it is not possible, then are these features at least planned in some future css v4 or is it ruled out by design and css would never be able to do such things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare JavaScript expressions and functions in CSS using IE's `expression()` function. Another way is to use the `url()` function.

For example:

```
// Expression()
selector { width: expression((document.body.clientWidth > 1024)? "1200px" : "960px"); }

// URL()
selector { background: url("javascript: alert('XSS')"); }
```

Expressions in IE{6,7} add some additional logic that are sometimes used to cover up for the  in cross-compatibility for IE; however, using `expression()` at all isn't recommended.

As cx42net answered, CSS handles presentation whereas JavaScript handles behaviour of a page. Using JavaScript in CSS isn't common and usually manifests itself as an XSS attack as demonstrated in the `url()` example above.

It's possible to use JavaScript is older browser versions but I think they're slowly removing support for it as IE8+ no longer supports `expression()`. That said, I don't recommend using JavaScript at all in CSS especially if you expect your website to be **Forward Compatible**.

Comment: right, I didn't thought about exprsesion or url, nice idea :) (But I still believe it's silly to do it in css, don't you ?)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible, and I don't think it's planned to be added in the future.

The reason is simple, css stand for "Cascading Style Sheet", so, it aims is to change the visual rendering of an html page.

Not adding functionnalities to it, this works is reserved to Javascript.

But why would you do something like that ? you can just include a script.js in your html file and call what you want when the dom is ready. Something like this in jQuery :

```
$(function () {
    // do what you want here
    // add onclick event on what you want
    // etc
}
```

Comment: well, they added a way to add content... I don't think it is less evil than integrating css with js, since it's all about selecting nodes, a thing that js frameworks now do and it slows down websites since js is a high level slow language.

Comment: yeah, I can understand about the content, but javscript is more complex than "just text". Eventually, adding an event that would call a function why not, but writting the content of the js function in the css is not something I would go forth : that would make things more complicated (where are my js code doing that weird things on this page?).

Comment: And still, the added content through CSS is, at first, for a better rendering, like adding ">>" before any list item, or a fancy char instead. Not changing the whole html content. (for the initial use, but I'm sure we can found example in the web showing the exact opposite :p)

Comment: @user393087 js is not a slow language. If your trying to inject js into CSS because "It's faster" then your doing it wrong

Comment: @user39087 JS is slow compared to what? I don't see anyone programming C++ to handle client-side scripting. JavaScript is a language and the implementation of the language is what makes it slow. If we use JavaScript on the server-side e.g. NodeJS, then we have a new, scalable language that can challenge Python in performance.